# How to resolve the error react with yii2, has been blocked by CORS policy: Response?

Tags: php, yii2, cors

I have a yii2 app for the backend and I am using react for the frontend.
I try now through an api call the login function. But I get this error when I try to login on the frontend:

```
login/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What I already tried. I found this link:

```
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-cors
```

But didn't resolved the problem.

So I try to configure the controller from yii2 , that it can communicate with the frontend.

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\v1\controllers;
use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\Cors;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';

    protected $_verbs = ['POST','OPTIONS'];

    public function behaviors(){

       

        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

         // remove auth filter before cors if you are using it
         unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],

             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*', 'http://localhost:3000'],

            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],

            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],

            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,

            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,

            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
            ],
        ];
       
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options', 'login'];

        return $behaviors;
    }
 

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $username = Yii::$app->request->post('username');
        $password = Yii::$app->request->post('password');

        $user = User::findByUsername($username);

        if ($user && $user->validatePassword($password)) {
            return ['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Login successful'];
        } else {
            Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 401;
            return ['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid username or password'];
        }
    }


    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    private $_user;

     
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
           
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],            
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],            
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }
  
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
```

and user:

```
<?php
// phpcs:ignoreFile

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\filters\Cors;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 9;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;
   
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::class,
        ];
    }


    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

  
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
           
             
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'default', 'value' => null],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['username', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email', 'verification_token'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            [['password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
            [['username'], 'unique'], 
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

     
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
    }

      
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

  
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }
}
```

and web.php file:

```
<?php
// phpcs:ignoreFile

$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'name' => 'internetsuite 2.0',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\v1\Module',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [

            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'OEtCunrAfQNETtmUSDnZw1JPHTB44i3A',
        ],
        

        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => \yii\symfonymailer\Mailer::class,
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,

    'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' =>  [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/user',                 
                'patterns'=>[
                    'POST' => 'signup',
                    'POST login' => 'login',
                    'OPTIONS login' => 'options',

                ],
            
            ],                           
            
        ],

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

and react login call looks:

```
/* eslint-disable newline-before-return */
import { UserProfileToken } from "../models/User";
import axios from "axios";
import { handleError } from "../helpers/ErrorHandler";

const api = "http://localhost:8080/v1/";

export const loginAPI = async (username: string, password: string) => {
  try {
    const data = await axios.post<UserProfileToken>(api + "user/login", {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    });
    return data;

  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
};
}
```

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            
            'rules' =>  [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/user', 
                'patterns' => [
                    'POST' => 'signup',
                    'POST login' => 'login',
                    'OPTIONS login' => 'options',                    
                ],
                
                
            ],                         
            
        ],
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: yii\web\UrlRule::POST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your rules settings for `UrlManager`. Request being blocked by CORS policies despite using `yii\filters\Cors` is the result of these issues too.

First of all, in this part of configuration:

```php
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/user',
    'POST' => 'v1/user/signup',
]
```

The part `'POST' => 'v1/user/signup'` doesn't work. I'm not sure if you just left out too much when copying your code to question or if this is how you have your settings in your project. The issue is that in `yii\rest\UrlRule` configuration for matching methods to actions have to be part of [`$patterns`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$patterns-detail) or [`$extraPatterns`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$extraPatterns-detail) properties. The main difference between these two properties is that `$patterns` contain some default patterns used by actions in `yii\rest\ActiveConroller`.
So the rest rule configuration should look for example like this:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/user',
    'patterns' => [
        'POST' => 'signup',
        // ... patterns for other HTTP methods
    ]
]
```

The reason why the signup might seem to work was probably because the request matched default post pattern. It looks like this `'POST' => 'create'`. The creation of user was handled by [`yii\rest\CreateAction`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-createaction) which is part of default `yii\rest\ActiveController` [actions](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/a292af13bf78c56629bb38312866cb0c417588d8/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L73).

Another issue is that if you want your rest controller to handle url in format like `module/controller/action` (eg. `v1/user/login`) you have explicitly add the pattern for this route. This is because `yii\rest\UrlRule` doesn't use the usual `controller/action` matching standard rules does.
So, with added pattern for `v1/user/login` POST requests the config might look like this:

```php
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/user',
    'patterns' => [
        'POST' => 'signup',
        'POST login' => 'login',
        // ... patterns for other HTTP methods
    ]
]
```

Now we are finally getting to CORS blocking part. When browser is going to send AJAX POST request the first thing it does is something called "CORS preflight". This means it tries to send OPTIONS request to same url it's going to send the POST request to retrieve CORS headers first. Your `UrlManager` doesn't know how to handle OPTIONS request for `v1/user/login` route. The request doesn't reach your `UserController` and `yii\filters\Cors` is never applied to that request. Because of that browser doesn't get proper CORS headers and the POST request is blocked.
To avoid that we need to add pattern for OPTIONS request to our configuration, for example like this:

```php
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/user',
    'patterns' => [
        'POST' => 'signup',
        'POST login' => 'login',
        'OPTIONS login' => 'options',
        // ... patterns for other HTTP methods
    ]
]
```

To avoid CORS blocking using [`options`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-optionsaction) action that already exists among `yii\rest\ActiveController` default actions is good enough. For proper REST API you might want to make sure that only supported methods are returned in response to OPTIONS request.

Comment: The `'POST' => ...` or `'OPTIONS login' => ...` must be part of `'patterns'` or `'extraPatterns'` arrays. The `UnknownPropertyException` should only be rised if they are outside of those arrays.

Comment: Edited urlManager settings in your question looks fine and it definitively should throw that error. There are two things I can think of. 1) Some mismatched brackets are messing with the configuration. 2) The configuration file you are editing is not actually the one that is used (because of cache or something).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand it. And I have to deep dive more in to this stuff. But it works. In the UserController I added this

```
public function behaviors()
{
      // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = [
            'options',
            'login',
            'signup',                  
        ];

}
```

And It doesn't throw anymore all the CORS errors stuff